# Angular2 get <ul><li> values

Tags: jquery, html, angular

Hello I have a dual tag list and I want to get the values of the `<li>` tags on the right side. I need the values within an array or just as string.

I tried with `[(ngModel)]` for each `<li>` tag but I am getting an error

> No value accessory exists

How can I solve this?

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-12"  style="margin-top:40px; padding-left:0!important;" >
       <div class="dual-list list-left col-md-5">
          <div class="well listDual">
             <h4 class="text-center"><b>Tagliste</b></h4>
             <hr/>
             <ul class="list-group ul" >
                <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let x of dataTagListSorted;"> </li>
             </ul>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="list-arrows col-md-1 text-center">
          <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm move-left">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          </button>
          <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm move-right" >
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" ></span>
          </button>
       </div>
       <div class="dual-list list-right col-md-5">
          <div class="well listDual">
             <h4 class="text-center"><b>Tags</b></h4>
             <hr/>
             <ul class="list-group ul">
       //This is my taglist on the right side
             </ul>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
 $('body').one('click', '.list-group .list-group-item', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

$('body').one('click', '.move-left', function() {
    let actives = $('.list-right ul li.active');
    actives.clone().prependTo('.list-left ul');



    actives.remove();
});
$('body').one('click', '.move-right', function() {

            let actives = $('.list-left ul li.active');
            actives.clone().appendTo('.list-right ul');

            actives.remove();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code

```
 <ul class="list-group ul">
    <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let x of dataTagListSorted;let i = index;">
        <input [(ngModel)]="dataTagListSorted[i]" type="text" />
    </li>
 </ul>
```

When you use ngFor, Angular doesn't create new variables, so you can't bind `x` to your `ngModel`. That's why you have to use the index and the array.

You can do the same for the other list too.

**EDIT** If you want to manage clicks :

```
 <ul class="list-group ul">
    <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let x of dataTagListSorted;let i = index;">
        <button (click)="getValue(x, i)">{{x}}</button>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

and in your Component TS file :

```
getValue(x, index): void {
    console.log(x);
    console.log(this.dataTagListSorted[index]);
}
```

Both logs will give you the value.

**EDIT 2** If you want to switch one item from a list to the other, do like so.

For your lists :

```
 <ul class="list-group ul">
    <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let x of leftList;let i = index;">
        <button (click)="sendToRight(x, i)">{{x}}</button>
    </li>
 </ul>

 <ul class="list-group ul">
    <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let x of rightList;let i = index;">
        <button (click)="sendToLeft(x, i)">{{x}}</button>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

And in your component :

```
sendToRight(x, i) {
    this.leftList.splice(i, 1);
    this.rightList.push(x);
}

sendToLeft(x, i) {
    this.rightList.splice(i, 1);
    this.leftList.push(x);
}
```

Comment: Ok, how can I get the values with [(ngModel)]="dataTagListSorted[i]"  within my component?

Comment: If you used this line of code, in your component, you just have to use `this.dataTagListSorted[index]`, where `index` is the correct index. See the edit on my post to know how to get it.

Comment: Ok I see but just need the values from the right taglist <ul class="list-group ul">
       //This is my taglist on the right side
             </ul

Comment: As you can see for yourself, you didnt put any ngFor in the second list. So I can't help you unless you put a ngFor in it, or at least give me the name of the array containing the second list.

Comment: I am getting can not push of undefined even I am getting the value. getLIValues(){
  $('.list-right ul li').each(function(i, elem)
  {
    let data = $(elem).text();
    console.log(data)
    this.leftTaglist.push(",",data.toString() )

  });
}

Comment: This is nasty ... Be glad I can read it. What you are doing is also nasty : why do you use JQuery to populate your Angular variables ? Plus, if you do that, your left list will be empty since you have nothing in your right list. But I can see what you want to do. I will edit my answer and let you know when I'm done

Comment: This I understood but my button to right is not within a loop. Check please my html again

Comment: Then change your HTML. From what I see, you install a whole framework (Angular), and use another one (JQuery) without using the first one. You should use Angular here, it will be much easier for you

Answer (score 2):

Don't use Jquery. Use `*ngFor` in your `li`. `*ngFor` will bind from array in your Component. If you need to get value with event click, use `(click)="myFct(item)"`.

**HTML**

```
 <ul class="list-group ul">
           <li class="list-item-group" *ngFor="let item of myArray" (click)="myFct(item)>{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
```

**Angular Component**

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    public myArray: Array<any>;

    constructor() {};

    ngOnInit() { 
        myArray = [1,2,3]
    }

   myFct(item){
        console.log(item)
   }
}
```